# Redirecting to ASP.NET MVC application from ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have two web applications (two virtual directories) - One is asp.net web application and other is asp.net mvc application. I would like to redirect certain type of users to my mvc application from my legacy web application.

How to acheive this ?

Please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Response.Redirect

```
if(someConditionIsMet)
{
   Response.Redirect("http://www.example.com/MVCApp/");
}
```

EDIT: Updated to direct to full path rather than the root.
EDIT2: Updated the URL to show an MVC route rather than an physical page address.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But my question is both are two separate virtual directories.so how do i hop from legacy web app to new mvc app. Only way is Response.redirect ?

Comment: I don't see the problem. Instead of using the root '~' just use the full path including domain name.

Comment: Two virtual directories means two different websites , whether or not in same IIS does not matter. You will have to specify the full HTTP path to the other page to be redirected to. Either construct the path with domain name programatically or pick it up from config file.

Comment: Also, it is worth noting in the example supplied than an actual MVC app would have a URL that looks like "index.aspx" but would rather target a URL Route like "/MVCApp/" which would evaluate to the default view for that controller.